# jQuery checkbox checked works for all inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have the following script

```
<script>

    $('input:checkbox').live('change', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('checked');
        } else {
            alert('un-checked');
        }
    });

</script>
```

So, the problem is that I have more than one checkbox so it gives at each checkbox an alert.. And I just want to give an alert when the user selects one specific checkbox.

Thanks!

Comment: Give that specific checkbox an ID and target that instead of targeting all inputs.

Comment: if  you want the change event to be trigger only for one specific text box then kindly use a specific selector preferable the id selector . For example $("#specific")

Comment: I'm sorry, but how? I mean, I don't have many experience with javascript/jQuery..

Comment: there are lots of options, do as the previous post suggests or another alternative would be to place your checkbox inside a div and use the div when listening for the click event $('#part1 :checkbox').click(function(){
    // code goes here
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an id or a class on the checkbox.  Your current code is looking at each input:checkbox.

Change this:

```
$('input:checkbox').live('change', function(){
```

To

```
$('#idofcheckbox').live('change', function(){
```

Then add the id to the checkbox:

```
<input type=checkbox id="idofcheckbox">
```

Comment: @Jérémy -- np, glad we could help!